# Using string builder to append

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I have created object of string builder and using it to append the words. But it is throwing error.

```
package learningPackage;

    public class StringBuilder {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String[] words = {"This", "is", "a", "sentence", "done","using", "string", "builder"};
            StringBuilder mySB = new StringBuilder();

            for (String word: words) {
                mySB.append(word);
                mySB.append(" ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Expected the code to work fine. however it is throwing error on mySB.append(word).

> Error : the method append(string) is undefined for the type string
>   builder

Comment: this is resolved now. I realized that class name  cannot be string builder which I had used.

Answer (score 0):

Please rename the class name and it will work fine. The problem is the conflicting class name.

Answer (score 0):

That is because in StringBuilder there is no method or constructor which takes StringBuilder as an argument.
Below is the list of methods in StringBuilderClass:

```
StringBuilder append(boolean b)
StringBuilder append(char c)
StringBuilder append(char[] str)
StringBuilder append(char[] str, int offset, int len)
StringBuilder append(double d)
StringBuilder append(float f)
StringBuilder append(int i)
StringBuilder append(long lng)
StringBuilder append(Object obj)
StringBuilder append(String s)
```

Hence the exception.

The principal operations on a StringBuilder that are not available in String are the append() and insert() methods, which are overloaded so as to accept data of any type. Each converts its argument to a string and then appends or inserts the characters of that string to the character sequence in the string builder. The append method always adds these characters at the end of the existing character sequence, while the insert method adds the characters at a specified point.

**Note:** You can use any String method on a StringBuilder object by first converting the string builder to a string with the toString() method of the StringBuilder class. Then convert the string back into a string builder using the StringBuilder(String str) constructor.